# How can I implement a handle to use in another class as well as the class it was made in? C++

Tags: c++, windows, memory-editing

i'm working on a program where i need the handle of the program to be able to be used in the other classes and without changing the value, ive tried changing class to struct, didn't work, i tried to copy the handle into the protected part of attach. So how do i implement the varible handle to other classes.

```
struct attach
{
//Tried this HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, ProcID);
void Attach(char* name)
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, name);
        if (hwnd == NULL)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to attach Window", "attention", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << hwnd << endl;
            DWORD ProcID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcID);
           if(handle == NULL)
            {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to obtain Process ID", "attention", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, ProcID);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ProcID << endl;;
                cout << handle;
            }
        }
}
protected:
  };

class Sonic_Heroes : protected attach
{
protected:
void cp()
{
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)RINGS, &NEWRINGS, sizeof(int), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)LIVES, &NEWLIVES, sizeof(int), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)TEAMBLAST, &NEWTEAMBLAST, sizeof(int), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)FLIGHTHEIGHT, &NEWFLIGHTHEIGHT, sizeof(float), 0);
}
char name[18]= "SONIC HEROES(TM)";
const DWORD RINGS = 0x009DD70C;
const DWORD LIVES = 0x009DD74C;
const DWORD TEAMBLAST = 0x009DD72C;
const DWORD FLIGHTHEIGHT = 0x00789FA4;
int NEWRINGS;
int NEWLIVES;
int NEWTEAMBLAST;
float NEWFLIGHTHEIGHT;
};
 class Sonic_Mania : protected attach
 {
 protected:
void CP()
{
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)RINGS, &NEWRINGS, sizeof(int), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)SCORE, &NEWSCORE, sizeof(int), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)LIVES, &NEWLIVES, sizeof(int), 0);
}
char name[13]= "Sonic mania";
const DWORD RINGS = 0x00A4D644;
const DWORD SCORE = 0x00A4D654;
const DWORD LIVES = 0x00A4D650;
int NEWRINGS;
int NEWSCORE;
int NEWLIVES;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`HANDLE handle` is a local variable in the method `Attach`, not part of the class/struct. Create a `HANDLE` member in the struct and it could work (cannot try it):

```
struct attach
{
HANDLE handle; // if handle has no default constructor you need to use pointers

void Attach(char* name)
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, name);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to attach Window", "attention", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << hwnd << endl;
        DWORD ProcID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcID); // here an if-statement is missing i think?
        if(handle == NULL) 
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to obtain Process ID", "attention", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, ProcID);
        }
        else // this won't compile
        {
            cout << ProcID << endl;;
            cout << handle;
        }
    }
}
};
```

Comment: i moving the handle but the issue is the handle is needed in the attach class and even copying it wont do get the process id and print the cant obtain process id message box.

Comment: I made a mistake in the code. What is the problem right now?

Comment: i forgot to put if(handle == NULL) because if it does return NULL it cant find the Process ID, so how do i use it in two classes and keep it value, anything i change it causes something else not to work

Comment: Two keep the same value (without copying) in two classes or more, you have to use pointers. As I can't see another class, I can't say how to do it.

Comment: the other classes are on the question, its class sonic heroes & sonic mania class. i would really appreciate your help if you can